# JQuery add row dynamically in Play framework

Tags: jquery, playframework

In play 2 framework I am using a function to create table rows (Given below). How do I use Jquery add a new row in the table with new Id and name.

```
 @repeatWithIndex(computerForm("customObjects"), min = 5) { (lineorder, index) =>   
                            @objectRow(index, lineorder, false)

                            @(skuCounter+=1)
 }

@objectRow(id: Int, lineorder: Field, hide: Boolean) = {


        <td width="3%">@inputText1(lineorder("parentName"), "input-large") </td>
        <td width="10%">@inputText1(lineorder("name"), "input-medium") </td>
        <td width="10%">@inputText1(lineorder("field"), "input-medium") </td>
        <td width="10%">
        @defining(lineorder("type")) { uidField =>
             <input type="text" class=" content-box typeahead  input-medium" name="@uidField.name" 
             value="@uidField.value" data-provide="typeahead" autocomplete="off"
                data-source='["email", "digits", "number", "date", "block"]'>
        }</td>

        <td width="15%">@inputText1(lineorder("regrep"), "content-box input-large")</td>
        <td width="15%">@inputText1(lineorder("exclude"), "content-box input-large")</td>
        <td>
        @if(id <= 10) {
            <a href="#lsRet" onclick="addRow('orow', @(id + 1))"><i class="icon-plus"></i></a>
        } 
        @if(id > 1) {
            <a href="#lsRet" onclick="hideRow('orow', @(id))" title="Pattern"><i class="icon-minus"></i></a>
        }
        </td>
    </tr>
```

}

inputText1 generates following HTML code :
`<input class="content-box input-xs" name="nodes[5].order" value="5" type="text">`

I want to update the nodes index (5) to next index.

Comment: I'm kinda confused with what you want to achieve.. By saying, "with new Id and name", can you explain which `<td>` you want to assign new Id and name ? Can you give the sketch about how you want to generate your table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I assume that your code works fine and you just want to use jQuery to add a new row into the table with next index value.. Here is how to do it:

First, you need to get the latest index from your table. You can get this value by checking the number of rows, `<tr>`, that were already in the table using jQuery [length](http://api.jquery.com/length/).

```
temp = $("#table_id tr").length;
```

If your starting index is 1 then you need to add 1 to the length value.

```
temp = $("#table_id tr").length + 1;
```

Then, you can use [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to add a new HTML tag with the next index(in `temp` variable) into your current HTML.

```
$("#table_id").append('<input class="content-box input-xs" name="nodes['+temp+'].order" value="5" type="text">');
```